# Combining MKOverlays

Tags: uiview, mapkit

I need to draw many (hundreds to thousands) of square overlays on a map. The positions and sizes of these overlays stay constant. I think that I can speed up rendering by combining these square overlays into a single overlay so drawMapRect only needs to be called once. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, removing overlays is not an option. A way I found to drastically improve performance was to have my overlay class store an array of the square overlays. Then in my overlayView's drawMapRect method, I looped over the array to draw all the overlays. Something very similar is done in the [HazardMap Apple Developer Example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/HazardMap/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010049-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2). See drawMapRect in HazardMapView.m

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem for MKAnnotation.
And I found following link:

http://www.fiveminutes.eu/having-fun-with-ios-map-kit-grouping-annotations/

Iterate annotation list and calculate a distance of two annotation's coordinate.
If there's nearby annotation exist, remove it from the list.

I think this approach can be applicable to MKOverlays too.